# Disappearing Geometry with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYArMj542LY&list=PL70822sOht7266mdEBxZ8Rb4PGTCRFgLy&index=2&t=185s)

What should happen is, it should create a Thanos snap cease to exist effect.

To me, my node setup looks exactly like his, but my geometry is just gone after adding a point instance node. I'm also not sure if my empties are setup correctly.

Can anyone help me see what I'm missing?

Here's my [blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/d085ff1ea042499586a614323d5fa6a9)

Comment: Hello, could you add a little more information in the body of your question ? It should stand on its own without relying on links to external websites which may go extinct in the future

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did "point instance" your own object. Put another instance in there e.g. a cube or a sphere, then it "works" better, but looks like there are even more problems in there...

[image]